# find script should remove empty dir recursively after it removes files in it

Tags: linux, find

I've this find script that finds files in the /home directory of more than 100 MB in size and deletes if it is more than 10 days old. It is scheduled for every day one time by cron job.

```
find /home/ -mtime +10 -type f -size +100M -delete >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Now, I want this script to remove directories recursively from where it removes files, as it is leaving empty directories.

Could anyone advise or suggest what change needs to be done in this script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On a GNU system, you could do:

```
find /home/ -mtime +10 -type f -size +100M -delete -printf '%h\0' |
  awk -v RS='\0' '!seen[$0]++ {out = out $0 RS}
                  END {printf "%s", out}' |
  xargs -r0 rmdir
```

We use `awk` to filter out duplicate while still keeping the order (leaves before the branch they're on) and also delay the printing until all the files have been removed so `rmdir` can remove empty directories.

With `zsh`:

```
files=(/home/**/*(D.LM+100m+10od))
rm -f $files
rmdir ${(u)files:h}
```

Note that those would remove the directories that become empty after *files* are removed from them, but not the parent of those directories if they don't have any of those files to delete and become empty as a result of the *directories* being removed. If you want to remove those as well, with GNU `rmdir`, you can add the `-p`/`--parents` option to `rmdir`.

If you wanted to remove all empty directories regardless of whether files or directories have been removed from them or not, still with GNU `find`, you could do:

```
 find /home/ \( -mtime +10 -type f -size +100M -o -type d -empty \) -delete
```

Comment: Neither solution removes directories that become empty because their children were all directories that just got removed.

Comment: @Gilles, good point. Answer updated.

Comment: `cd /home && find . -depth -mtime +10 -type f -size +100M -delete -o -type d -empty -delete`

Comment: @Rakesh, yes, though like for Philippos' answer, that would also delete directories that were empty beforehand. I've added a variant to the answer though, making the implications clear.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you remove all empty dirs in a second run afterwards (`find` option `-empty` along with `-type d`?

Comment: Nope.  Try this: `mkdir -p a/b/c; find . -type d -empty`.  You'd get back `./a/b/c`, not `./a`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura, `find . -type d -empty -delete` (which implies `-depth`) will delete them however. The problem here is that it would also delete directories that were already empty before.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas What about symlink loops?

Comment: @SatoKatsura, what about them? `-type d` doesn't select symlinks and without `-L`/`-follow`, `find` doesn't follow symlinks.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
cd "/home" && \
find . -depth -type d ! -name . ! -empty -exec sh -c '
   find "$1" -mtime +10 -type f -size +100M -delete
' {} {} \; -empty -delete
```

## Summary

We need GNU find for the above to work. Basic idea being we invoke `find` with `-depth` mode
    which forces `find` to process child dirs earlier than their parents. Then we look at only
    dirs and only those that are nonempty thereby precluding `find` from deleting the originally
empty dirs.